# Is it possible to get Autocomplete results for addresses instead of places?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

The Google Places API exposes an autocomplete service that is useful for autocompleting *places* but sometimes I don't want places but *addresses*. I can see the difference when I type in my autocomplete widget and in actual Google Maps interface.

So, is it possible to actually use an address autocomplete API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add in an optional type to the autocomplete options of "geocode":

```
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));

var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
  bounds: defaultBounds,
  types: ['geocode']
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete#place_types shows the various options.

Comment: documentation says it will **restrict** the results, which might be the opposite of what I need right now...

Comment: it will restrict it by not including establishments, but will provide all geocodes